# puppeteer Image break issue

Tags: html, css, node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer

i am generating pdf from html. But cant generate proper. Signature image is break on another page. check below image. Is there any way that if content or image is break then it will move on another pdf page.

puppeteer version - 3.3.0
node version - 12.16.1

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYwVp.png)

Code:

```
await page.pdf({
                    path: pdfPath,
                    format: 'A4',
                    printBackground: true,
                    displayHeaderFooter: true,
                    headerTemplate: '<div id="header-template" style="font-size:10px !important; color:#808080; padding-left:10px"><span class="">Production</span></div>',
                    footerTemplate: '<div id="footer-template" style="font-size:10px !important; color:#808080; padding-left:10px"><span class="">Production</span><span class="pageNumber" style="font-size:10px !important; color:#808080; padding-left:200px"></span></div>',
                    margin: {
                        top: '100px',
                        bottom: '100px',
                        right: '30px',
                        left: '30px',
                    },
                });
html:
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;width: 98.5%;">
                <div id="signature">
                    <div class="sign">
                        <img src="{{signature}}" alt="sign"
                            style="margin-top: 10px;width: 120px;height: 120px;float: right;" />
                    </div>
                    <span>Signature By {{ signature_by }}<br>({{ signature_by_role }})</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#signature {
            float: right;
            width: auto;
            margin-right: 1%;
        }
        #signature img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #signature span {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            color: #000;
            float: left;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        .sign {
            min-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the css property break-inside: avoid; on signature